# Not able to use deployed model with LangChain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, langchain, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Can LangChain work with deployed model on GCP or does it only work with foundation models such as Palm2 etc. Here is my code:

```
# Import dependencies
import json
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.llms import VertexAIModelGarden
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.protobuf import json_format
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Value


llm = VertexAIModelGarden(endpoint_id=ENDPOINT_ID, project=PROJECT, location=LOCATION)

llm("What is the meaning of life?")
```

The following code ran into an error.